# I dont have sudo for reboot, but I want

Tags: reboot

I have a problem that when I type reboot to console it works. And I don't want that, I want to be asked to run it with sudo and password. I've done a few configurations to my ubuntu, and since I'm not an expert I might messed something up.

I work with small embedded devices with Linux on them, I am root there and I reboot them from time to time, so when I type reboot as a root I don't need sudo or a password. The problem is, when I type it by mistake to my local console and my PC reboots... But I'm not root on my PC, so how can I block it?